# If I write ObjectA+-ObjectB and overload + and - operators, which object gets which methods called on?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

I'm curious because I'm trying to negate an object(eg. -ObjA), and realized I'm shaky on how these operators would be called. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't piggyback. Write a proper, clear question, with a self-contained body.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry. I'll try to rewrite it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the operators as member functions, `ObjectA+-ObjectB` is just syntactic sugar for `ObjectA.operator+(ObjectB.operator-())`. If, on the other hand, you define them as free functions, it is just syntactic sugar for `operator+(ObjectA, operator-(ObjectB))`.

Comment: So for object B if I define operator-() member function, that corresponds to -B and if I define operator-(Object& another) that corresponds to B.operator-(A)?